# Keras model does not improve on multi-class classification problem

Tags: python, keras

I wanted to learn more about machine learning / deep learning so I have been attempting to solve the [Kaggle Diabetic Retinopathy](https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection) competition as a learning experience. **However, my Keras model's accuracy and loss function do not seem to improve.**

I downloaded the Diabetic Retinopathy dataset. Balanced the classes and created equally distributed batches of 100 images per batch. I have tried many combinations of parameterisation like more Epochs, different learning rates, complexer models, whatsoever. They all seem to have no effects. So here is my code.

My imports:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

My parameters:

```
HEIGHT = 512
WIDTH = 512
DEPTH = 3
inputShape = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH)
NUM_CLASSES = 5
EPOCHS = 15
INIT_LR = 0.001
BS = 1
```

I check the batches in a given directory:

```
''' read batches '''
train_dir = '/DATA/npy_data/train_dir/'
batch_path_list = []
for batch in tqdm(os.listdir(train_dir)):
    batch_full_path = os.path.join(os.path.sep, train_dir, batch)
    batch_path_list.append(str(batch_full_path))

AMOUNT_OF_BATCHES = len(batch_path_list)

if AMOUNT_OF_BATCHES == 0:
    print('We found no batches. Either no data or wrong directory...')

if AMOUNT_OF_BATCHES != 0:
    print('We found ' + str(AMOUNT_OF_BATCHES) + ' batches.')
```

I read the CSV file to obtain the labels

```
''' read csv labels '''
csv_dir = '/DATA/data/trainLabels_normalised.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_dir, sep=',')
patientIDList = []
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    patientID = row[0] + ''
    patientID = patientID.replace('_right', '')
    patientID = patientID.replace('_left', '')
    dataframe.at[index, 'PatientID'] = patientID
    patientIDList.append(patientID)
```

I create and compile my model

```
model = Sequential(name='test')

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(activation='softmax', units=5))

opt = optimizers.SGD(decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy", "mse"])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="/home/user/Desktop/code/model/best_weights.hdf5",
                               verbose=1,
                               save_best_only=True)
```

I load a batch and join the labels with the 100 images from the batch.

```
''' load batches '''
for item in batch_path_list:
    batch_data = np.load(item).tolist()
    df1 = dataframe[dataframe['image'].isin(batch_data)]
    imageNameArr = []
    dataArr = []

    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        key = str(row[0])
        if key in batch_data:
            imageNameArr.append(key)
            dataArr.append(batch_data[key])

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'image': imageNameArr, 'data': dataArr})
    for idx in range(0, len(df1)):
        if (df1.loc[df1.index[idx], 'image'] != df2.loc[df2.index[idx], 'image']):
            print("Error " + df1.loc[df1.index[idx], 'image'] + "==" + df2.loc[df2.index[idx], 'image'])

    merged_files = pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on='image', right_on='image', how='outer')
```

I generate splits

```
    train_ids, valid_ids = train_test_split(patientIDList, test_size=0.25, random_state=10)
    traindf = merged_files[merged_files.PatientID.isin(train_ids)] #data (data) image (img name) level (fase)
    valSet = merged_files[merged_files.PatientID.isin(valid_ids)]
    trainX = traindf['data']
    trainY = traindf['level']
    valX = valSet['data']
    valY = valSet['level']
    trainY = to_categorical(trainY, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
    valY = to_categorical(valY, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
    Xtrain = np.zeros([trainX.shape[0], HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH])
    Xval = np.zeros([valX.shape[0], HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH])
```

I use a generator and call the fit function.

```
    aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1,
                              height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
                              horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")


    model.fit_generator(aug.flow(Xtrain, trainY,
                        batch_size=BS),
                        validation_data=(Xval, valY),
                        steps_per_epoch=(len(trainX) // BS),
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        verbose=1,
                        callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

However, this results in a very low accuracy and does not seem to improve over 29 batches.

Result:

> 54/87 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6092 - acc: 0.2037 - mean_squared_error: 0.1599
>   56/87 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6089 - acc: 0.2143 - mean_squared_error: 0.1598
>   58/87 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6169 - acc: 0.2069 - mean_squared_error: 0.1605
>   60/87 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6146 - acc: 0.2167 - mean_squared_error: 0.1602
>   62/87 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6172 - acc: 0.2097 - mean_squared_error: 0.1605
>   64/87 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6196 - acc: 0.2031 - mean_squared_error: 0.1607
>   66/87 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6180 - acc: 0.2121 - mean_squared_error: 0.1605
>   68/87 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6164 - acc: 0.2206 - mean_squared_error: 0.1604
>   70/87 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6144 - acc: 0.2286 - mean_squared_error: 0.1602
>   72/87 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6163 - acc: 0.2222 - mean_squared_error: 0.1604
>   74/87 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6134 - acc: 0.2297 - mean_squared_error: 0.1601
>   76/87 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6102 - acc: 0.2368 - mean_squared_error: 0.1598
>   78/87 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6119 - acc: 0.2308 - mean_squared_error: 0.1600
>   80/87 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6159 - acc: 0.2250 - mean_squared_error: 0.1604
>   82/87 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6150 - acc: 0.2195 - mean_squared_error: 0.1603
>   84/87 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6206 - acc: 0.2143 - mean_squared_error: 0.1608
>   86/87 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6230 - acc: 0.2093 - mean_squared_error: 0.1610
>   87/87 [==============================] - 3s 31ms/step - loss: 1.6234 - acc: 0.2069 - mean_squared_error: 0.1610 - val_loss: 1.6435 - val_acc: 0.1282 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.1629
>   Epoch 00015: val_loss did not improve from 1.57533

Suggestions and feedback to improve my model are highly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this classification problem? Use cross entropy loss.

Comment: I am already using loss="categorical_crossentropy"

Comment: Isn't adding dropout after flattening is equivalent to removing vast swaths of data?

Comment: @user6916458 it is actually better to add dropout only in the Dense layer.

Comment: @user6916458 Even removing all the dropouts seem to have no effect. I am obviously doing something wrong but I cannot see what...

Comment: After Xtrain = np.zeors(...), Are you populating it with images?

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B Yes, if I print Xtrain it gives me the array [[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]

  ...,  etc. So basically an image's horizontal and vertical dimensions

Comment: If its giving you an array of zeros then it's not right. You need to put the images into that array

Comment: @RandomDNA true. It tells me that it is full of zeros. Is there image data in it? Use matplotlib's imshow() to visually verify. Because, np.zeros() created a numpy array with zeros.

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B I thought those were the pixel intensitities scaled from 0 to 1. But the print rounded the intensities so therefore I thought the "lower" values were represented as 0. 0. 0. instead of 0.0021321 etc. By the way plt.imshow() gives the following: TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B changing to np.ndarray() gives exactly the same

Comment: Using np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf) and we can see that its not all zero
67    [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [4.0, 4.0,...
68    [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0,...
69    [[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 1.0,...
70    [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0,...
71    [[[3.0, 1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0], [2.87695, ...
72    [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0,...
73    [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0224609], [0.0...